# Using Shadowsocks with Command Line Tools

Tags: networking, terminal, proxy, shadowsocks

I want to use Shadowsocks with Command Line Tools and I found a [tutorial](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Using-Shadowsocks-with-Command-Line-Tools). However it does not work for me. But I can open Twitter on Chrome using SwitchyOmega.

My `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf` file look like this:

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
quiet_mode

[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080
```

For exmpale, I curl Twitter like this.

```
proxychains4 curl https://www.twitter.com/
[proxychains] config file found: /Users/myname/.proxychains/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.12_1/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.twitter.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

PS: I'm from China and I have to use ShadowSocks since I can not visit Twitter website directly.

Comment: What does your proxychains.conf look like? Are you running the ShadowSocks service on port 1080?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I update my question. How can I know the ShadowSocks service runs on which port?

Comment: It would be in the documentation for that application, although that looks like the port it runs on by default. I'm mainly asking if you are running it at all.

Comment: Yes sure, if not I can not visit Twitter on Chrome.